# Foxpro Select Most Recent Order for Each Customer

Tags: visual-foxpro

In a foxpro table, I have 4 fields: ordernum, orderdate, ordertotal, custpk.

What is the foxpro select statement to return all of those fields from the most recent order for each custpk?

Comment: Before we can give you an answer, the first question to ask is:  what are the field types for ordernum & orderdate.   Is OrderNum a Numeric or Character type?  And is OrderDate a Date, DateTime, or Character type?   The SQL Query syntax will likely vary depending on your answer.

Comment: order date is a date field, ordernum is integer, ordertotal is N 9,2, Custpk is integer.  For clarity, this is a foxpro table and I need a foxpro command, not SQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table structure and what you want is not very clear. How do you define the "most recent order" for a given customer? Let's assume orderNum is primary key in that table and you decide "most recent order" for a given customer by the row having highest orderNum per customer. Then it is easy and a single VFP select command is sufficient (actually there are many SQL select variations that would return you the result you need. Below is one of those that would be most efficient):

```
select * from myTable ;
  where orderNum in ;
  (select max(orderNum) from myTable group by custPK)
```

BTW, VFP's SQL is close to ANSI-SQL 92.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a foxpro command, not SQL database

Let's start by saying that you will not get what you want with a single Foxpro command line.

Instead the most expedient manner to get this in Foxpro is to use Foxpro's SQL Query commands run on a FP/VFP Data Table and get the resultant data into a data table/cursor.

```
SELECT CustPk, OrderNum, OrderDate, OrderTotal FROM MyDataTable ORDER BY CustPk, OrderDate Desc INTO CURSOR OrderedData READWRITE
* --- Now ordered data is in memory cursor, use it however you need ---
* --- Each Customer's Most Recent Order will be first record ---
SELECT OrderedData
* --- You might just want to BROWSE the results to understand how the data appears ---
* --- Or you can do anything else with the data ---
< do whatever >
```

There are ways to get ONLY the most recent order per customer, but start here and see if that gets you what you need.

BTW: you might want to spend some time looking over the Free, On-line VFP tutorial videos at:
[Free Visual Foxpro Videos](http://www.garfieldhudson.com/freevideos.aspx)

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have done in the past and then delete all of the unneeded records.  I don't know foxpro's sql query as well as I should and resort to that all the time.  I would like to find how to do it with just the sql query command.

Comment: MOST of VFP's SQL Query syntax is the same as other database SQL Query syntax.  Admittedly there are some differences with FP/VFP, but try what you know and see if it works - it very likely will.   Then if it doesn't, just zero in on what part of the query syntax is not working and replace that part with FP/VFP command syntax instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to find how to do it with just the sql query command

Well I did it with just a SQL Query command, but you had to follow up with some other code.

EDIT: Oops:  I forgot that  Custpk is integer.
I am modifying the SQL Query syntax to take that into account.

Although it is still not a ONE LINE method, another way might be:

```
* --- Get reference records of only customer's last order date ---
SELECT STR(CustPk) AS cCustPk, MAX(OrderDate) AS LstOrdrDt FROM MyDataTable GROUP BY CustPk INTO CURSOR LstOrds READWRITE
* --- Now use that to get the complete last order for each customer ---
SELECT * FROM MyDataTable WHERE (STR(CustPk) + DTOS(OrderDate)) IN (SELECT cCustPk  + DTOS(LstOrdrDt) AS KeyExp FROM LstOrds) INTO CURSOR OnlyLstOrds READWRITE
* --- Now you have ONLY the last orders ---
SELECT OnlyLstOrds
< do whatever >
```

NOTE the above code is off-the-cuff and not tested, so there might be a typo in it which you can fix.

Also note that one of the Free, On-line VFP Tutorial Videos at that site is named:  **FoxPro and the SQL Language**

Good Luck

Comment: VFP supports subqueries and also derived queries. You could write that simply using a derived table: select * from myTable t1 inner join (select custPK, max(OrderDate) as maxDate from myTable group by custPK) t2 on t1.custPK = t2.custPK and t1.OrderDate = t2.OrderDate (however that wouldn't mean to return most recent order, unless on a given date there is only a single order for a given customer).